# Build static library with cgo under mips64le

Tags: go, mips, cgo

I’m trying to build a libtest.a with Go1.11.4 using cgo under linux/mips64le.
I make a simple Go file, this is test.go code:

```
package main
import(
    “C”
    “fmt”
)

func main() {
}

//export hello
func hello(){
    fmt.Println(“Hello World”)
}
```

and I did:

```
CGO_ENABLED=1 go build -o libtest.a -buildmode=c-archive test.go
```

I get these very non-descriptive errors:

```
# internal/race
flag provided but not defined: -shared
usage: compile [options] file.go...
(... many options such like -K, -L, -M etc.)
# internal/cpu
(...following like above)
# errors
# runtime/internal/sys
# math/bits
# runtime/internal/atomic
# sync/atomic
# math
# unicode/utf8
# unicode
# runtime/cgo
```

How can I do it? I can not use cgo under mips64le? best regards

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac, I build with:

```
GOOS=linux GOARCH=mips64le go build
```

It works well under mips64le(OS:NeoKylin).

Comment: Did you lets Go call C code, and compiled with CGO?